# what is the container port in kubernetes yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, devops

As we expose the container port in dockerfile itself then what is the use of container port in kubernetes yaml. What does it actually do. Is it mandatory to mention the container port in yaml file or we need not to mention in when we expose it in docker file.
Anyways, we will be using target port the map the container port with pod

ports:
        - containerPort: 80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ports :**

> containerPortList of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a
>   port here gives the system additional information about the network
>   connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not
>   specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed.
>   Any port which is listening on the default `"0.0.0.0"` address inside
>   a container will be accessible from the **network**. Cannot be
>   updated.

[container-core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#container-v1-core)

So it is exactly same with docker EXPOSE instruction. Both are informational. If you don’t configure ports in Kubernetes deployment, you can still access to the ports using Pod IP inside the cluster. You can create a service to access the ports externally without configuring ports in the deployment. But it is good to configure. It will help you or others to understand the deployment configuration better.

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published.

[.docker-reference-builder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)